# Object of class \BackendBundle\Entity\Categoria could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have created a database with products and categories:

```
CREATE TABLE categoria(
id       int(255) auto_increment not null,
nombre     varchar(50),
CONSTRAINT pk_categoria PRIMARY KEY(id),
)ENGINE = InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE producto(
id       int(255) auto_increment not null,
nombre     varchar(50),
categoria int(11),
createdAt datetime,
updatedAt datetime,
CONSTRAINT pk_producto PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_producto_categoria FOREIGN KEY(categoria) references categoria(id),
)ENGINE = InnoDb;
```

When printing with twig the product, and it shows all the fields, except the one of the category number, that I get the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable >Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__\BackendBundle\Entity\Categoria >could not be converted to string").

Any idea to solved this issue?

---

### producto.orm.yml

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Producto:
    type: entity
    table: producto
    indexes:
        fk_producto_categoria:
            columns:
                - categoria
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nombre:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 100
            options:
                fixed: false
        createdat:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
            column: createdAt
        updatedat:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
            column: updatedAt
    manyToOne:
        categoria:
            targetEntity: Categoria
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                categoria:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

---

### categoria.orm.yml

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Categoria:
    type: entity
    table: categoria
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nombre:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 50
            options:
                fixed: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

---

### producto.php

```
<?php

namespace BackendBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Producto
 */
class Producto
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $nombre;

   /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $categoria;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     *
     * @return Producto
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set categoria
     *
     * @param integer $categoria
     *
     * @return Producto
     */
    public function setCategoria($categoria)
    {
        $this->categoria = $categoria;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoria
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCategoria()
    {
        return $this->categoria;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function __toString(){

        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Producto
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Producto
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }   

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $createdat;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedat;

}
```

Comment: at some point, you try something like `echo $something`, where `$something` is an instance of `Categoria`. If you want to print all of the properties, use an appropiate function for this purpose, e.g. `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: This is about a rendering error... Can you show us the twig code you use?

Comment: {{ producto.categoria.nombre }}

Comment: Thanks to Tobias F. and Veve!
The solution is {{ producto.categoria.nombre }}  said by Arne
A lot of thanks!

Comment: Alright then !!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to "echo" an object through Twig. In this case the "Categoria" object. Instead of echoing the object, you problably want to echo the name like;

```
{{ producto.categoria.nombre }}
```

Another way to solve this problem is adding a __toString method to the Categoria entity like ;

```
class Categoria
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $nombre;

    ...

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre; 
    }
}
```

What you do here is tell PHP that whenever you access the object "Categoria" as a string, you should use its name. So when you try `echo $categoria` or `{{ categoria }}` PHP will look for the `__toString` method and echo whatever you return in that method.

Allthough I still prefer you explicitly use `{{ categoria.name }}` !